# Why is PHP not recognizing my User DSN?

Tags: php, codeigniter, odbc, netezza

I have successfully set up a user DSN on system called "NZSQL"

I am able to issue SQL commands on console using:

```
isql NZSQL
```

and run queries on the remote database system.

However in PHP I am executing the following piece of code:

```
$connect = odbc_connect("NZSQL","username","password");


        if(is_resource($connect)){ 
           echo "ok this is working";
        } else {
              echo "not working";
        }
```

I am getting a HTTP error 500 on Chrome and getting a blank screen in FF.

Oh btw I am using the code igniter framework.

Comment: Try to enable errors, so you can see what's wrong.  Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors',1);` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a white page, your PHP most likely is not working properly.

Do you get any errors? Check your PHP log. Is [ODBC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) properly installed? Check the output of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.